# PIL and Tkinter, multi windows

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have this message: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist .  I want to have multi windows with images , how ?

Here is my code:

```
import Image
import ImageTk
import Tkinter



def new():
    wind = Tkinter.Tk()
    wind.geometry('600x600')               # This not work, why? 
    imageFile2 = Image.open("someimage2.jpg")
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFile2)

    panel2 = Tkinter.Label(wind , image=image2)
    panel2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
    wind.mainloop()

master = Tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry('600x600')               # This work fine
imageFile = Image.open("someimage.jpg")
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFile)

panel1 = Tkinter.Label(master , image=image1)
panel1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
B = Tkinter.Button(master, text = 'New image', command = new).pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `wind = Tkinter.Tk()` to `wind = Tkinter.Toplevel()`:

```
def new():
    wind = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    wind.geometry('600x600')
```

That's all you need to change.

---

Reference:

- [Tkinter Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Comment: Niceeeee  unutbu,  you help me every time , Thanks !

Comment: This answer helped me too. However, I now see an additional small, empty frame that pops up alongside my program's top frame. Any thoughts on how to get rid of this?

Comment: @ealfonso: This question is about how to create two separate windows. The "small empty frame" you are seeing is probably one of these windows with no widgets inside. If you want just one window then your program should call `root = Tkinter.Tk()`, and never call `Tkinter.Toplevel()`.

Comment: But the reason I used your solution was that using `root = Tkinter.Tk()` did not let me display an image. I was getting `image "pyimage2" doesn't exist`, like the OP. Is there a way to address that error without creating the unwanted window?

Comment: Are you calling `Tkinter.Tk()` more than once? If so, that is the problem. For an example of how to display an image, see [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). If that does not clear up the issue, please post a new question with your code.

Comment: I changed to `root = Tkinter.Tk()` and somehow now it seems to work fine. A bit confused, but I won't bother. Thanks!